# Questions involving two polynomials

Tags: polynomials

Let $$P(x)=x^{6}-x^{5}-x^{3}-x^{2}-x$$
$$Q(x)=x^{4}-x^{3}-x^{2}-1$$

Let $z_{1}, z_{2}, z_{3}, z_{4}$ be the roots of Q(x)
Prove that $$P\left (z_{1}  \right )+ P\left (z_{2}  \right )+ P\left (z_{3}  \right )+ P\left (z_{4}  \right )=6$$

Comment: You meant to not put a 4th power term in the expression for $P(x)$, right?

Comment: Since you know what $Q(z_i)$ is, this should lead you to try to express as much as possible of $P(x)$ in terms of $Q(x)$. You can start out with $x^2 Q(x)$, and work with what's left. Also, if I recall correctly you eventually need to know what $z_1 + z_2 + z_3 + z_4$ is, maybe even $z_1^2 + z_2^2 + z_3^2 + z_4^2$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$P(x)=Q(x)(x^2+1)+(x^2-x+1)$, hence $\sum P(z_i)= \sum z_i^2  -\sum z_i +4 $. By Vieta's formulas $\sum z_i=1$ and $\sum z_i^2=(\sum z_i)^2-2\sum z_iz_j=1+2=3$. So $\sum P(z_i)=6$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

So, $$z_1^4-z_1^3-z_1^2-1=0\ \ \ \ \ (1)$$

$$P(z_1)=z_1^6-z_1^5-z_1^3-z_1^2-z_1$$
$$=z_1^2(z_1^4-z_1^3-z_1^2-1)+z_1^4-z_1^3-z_1=z_1^2-z_1+1$$

Let $z_1^2-z_1+1=y$

$$z_1^4-z_1^3-z_1^2-1=z_1^2(z_1^2-z_1+1)-2z_1^2-1=z_1^2y-2(y-1+z_1)-1$$
$$=(y+z_1-1)y-2(y-1+z_1)-1$$

$$\implies (y+z_1-1)y-2(y-1+z_1)-1=0$$

Express $z_1$ in terms of $y$ and put the value in $(1)$

Then use Vieta's formulas [1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas),[2](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Vieta%27s_Formulas),[3](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VietasFormulas.html)